# How to get the screensize to set the size of widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, layout, tabbar, adaptive-design

I have this code where it'll get the screen width to calculate and set tab adaptive width accoridng to screensize. It works fine in debug mode but In release mode the tab always found to be scrollable with large amoung of width. `isScrollable` property of Tabbar is set to `true` to provide desired width for tabs.

```
final double screenWidth = Data.screen.width;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 4);
    _tabController.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
    tabWidth = screenWidth / 4.8;
  }


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> myTabs = [
      const HomePageTab(
        icon: Icons.groups_rounded,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: tabWidth,
        child: const HomePageTab(
          title: 'Chats',
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: tabWidth,
        child: const HomePageTab(
          title: 'Status',
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: tabWidth,
        child: const HomePageTab(
          title: 'Calls',
        ),
      ),
    ];
```

.

```
In release mode
```

[image]

```
In Debug mode
```

[image]

Comment: can you try `flutter clean` and rebuild in release as test case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size`